# SELECT DISTINCT in PartiQL (AWS DynamoDB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, distinct, dynamodb-queries, partiql

I am running the following query in the AWS DynamoDB PartiQL editor:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1
FROM "my_lucky-table" 
WHERE Id = "db05-5d1"
```

but I am getting the following error:

> ValidationException: Unsupported token in expression: DISTINCT

Any idea how to deal with this? If `DINSTICT` is not supported in PartiQL what else can I run in order to get the unique values from `column1` ?? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PartiQL does not support `Distinct`. I'm not sure what data type your `column1` is but for the most part you would need to do the distinct filtering on your client side not on the DynamoDB side.

Comment: Is there any indirect way to get the unique values from a column in PartiQL? Or we are doomed?

Comment: Doomed I'm afraid. I'm guessing you mean unique across all items? There is no such thing as a column in DynamoDB, having that mindset is leading you to believe something like this can be achieved. You must think of DynamoDB as schemaless where each item acts alone.

Comment: Not doomed lol You can create a secondary index that lets you do that using the right composite key. Sorry, almost a year later :(